# Trigger action when submitting form with WPForms

Tags: forms, json

A customer of mine uses the WPForms plugin to create a front-end form. When the form is submitted the entry goes in de database (in a separate table wp_wpform_entries or something like that, all handled by the plugin).

But they also want to post all data to another website in JSON format. Is there a way to know the form is submitted or is the best way to use the `add_filter('wp_insert_post)?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the action [`wpforms_process_entry_save`](https://developers.wpforms.com/docs/action-wpforms_process_entry_save/).

```
add_action('wpforms_process_entry_save', 'your_submit_json_function', 10, 4);
```

Check the `actions` list [here](https://developers.wpforms.com/categories/actions/)

Comment: Thanks Yuri, that was exactly the thing I was searching for!
(Searched the internet but didn't find any of PHP stuff for WP forms)